# SSL protocol format version compatibility (message format versino VS encryption version)

Tags: ssl, encryption

This is going to be a bit of an advanced question, so please ignore less advanced details. I have protocol question rather than how to fix it, but I need to provide some background.

Background:

- .NET/Windows by default disable SSLv3. There are registry matters, and code matters. For whatever reason, I could not activate SSLv3, but it doesn't matter, it can stay that way. TLS+ should work fine.
- The above is tested using OpenSSL client or .NET client, and a .NET server. SSL3 clients won't work and that is ok.
- I have a customized Cellular module that would connect through TCP, SSL encrypted.

Here is an example of the Client Hello message sent:

0x16 [0x03 0x00] 0x00 0x65
0x01 0x00 0x00 0x61 [0x03 0x03] 0x36 0xF4 0x42 0x51 0x6D 0xE8
0x84 0xA2 0xDA 0xD0 0x09 0x45 0xB5 0xA1 0x12 0x8A 0x6B 0x43
0x24 0x14 0xD7 0x86 0x48 0x28 0xAE 0x0D 0x90 0x50 0x5C 0x1B
0x20 0xA1 0x00 0x00 0x2A 0x00 0x6B 0x00 0x6A 0x00 0x3D 0x00
0x67 0x00 0x40 0x00 0x3C 0x00 0x39 0x00 0x38 0x00 0x35 0x00
0x33 0x00 0x32 0x00 0x2F 0x00 0x16 0x00 0x13 0x00 0x0A 0x00
0x05 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x15 0x00 0x12 0x00 0x09 0x00 0xFF 0x01
0x00 0x00 0x0E 0x00 0x0D 0x00 0x0A 0x00 0x08 0x04 0x01 0x02
0x01 0x04 0x02 0x02 0x02

As you can see if you know which bytes to look at:
1. Record format is version SSL 3.0 (0x0300)
2. Client Hello protocol version is TLS 1.2 (0x0303)

In other words, even though the overall message is not the extended TLS format, encryption request is TLS 1.2

I would have assumed that windows/.NET allow this because encryption level is still safe, and only the client hello format is unextended. I don't understand why it would still be rejected.

Questions:

1. Does it make sense that the cellular module is sending encryption level of TLS1.2 but with unextended SSLv3 format?
2. How to make windows allow this, but not SSLv3 encryption? It seems you cannot simply have this middle ground.

Comment: How do you know it is not supported?

Comment: Tested several different Windows/certificate setups anyways, but let's focus on allowing only TLS encryption.

If TCP client send SSLv3 record layer and SSLv3 as max protocol, fails  at ClientHello. Even if the client sends a SSL3 record and TLS1.2 (or 1 or 1.1) max protocol, it still fails at ClientHello.

Fails for “The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm”

If certificate is made based on older ciphers it still fails at ClientHello.

Comment: The only way, it would not fail is that both record layer and max protocol are TLS. I have tampered with windows registry for SChannel as well to allow SSLv3 and older ciphers in a test server; that didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I simulated the client message, and gave it back to ssl server for testing purposes. Unextended protocol (original ssl3) ends up having AlgorithmMismatch, while extended protocol works even if I manually change its record layer version to SSL3.

This is failed:

```
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [4240] Exiting TcpClient#59817589::GetStream()  -> NetworkStream#48209832
System.Net Information: 0 : [4240] SecureChannel#5773521::.ctor(hostname=?124, #clientCertificates=0, encryptionPolicy=RequireEncryption)
System.Net Information: 0 : [4240] Enumerating security packages:
System.Net Information: 0 : [4240]     Negotiate
System.Net Information: 0 : [4240]     NegoExtender
System.Net Information: 0 : [4240]     Kerberos
System.Net Information: 0 : [4240]     NTLM
System.Net Information: 0 : [4240]     TSSSP
System.Net Information: 0 : [4240]     pku2u
System.Net Information: 0 : [4240]     WDigest
System.Net Information: 0 : [4240]     Schannel
System.Net Information: 0 : [4240]     Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider
System.Net Information: 0 : [4240]     CREDSSP
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [4240] Socket#6044116::BeginReceive()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [4240] Exiting Socket#6044116::BeginReceive()   -> OverlappedAsyncResult#63094882
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [8360] Data from Socket#6044116::PostCompletion
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [8360] 00000000 : 16 03 00 00 39                                  : ....9
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [8360] Socket#6044116::EndReceive(OverlappedAsyncResult#63094882)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [8360] Exiting Socket#6044116::EndReceive()     -> Int32#5
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [8360] Socket#6044116::BeginReceive()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [8360] Exiting Socket#6044116::BeginReceive()   -> OverlappedAsyncResult#62476613
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10888] Data from Socket#6044116::PostCompletion
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10888] 00000000 : 01 00 00 35 03 03 5A 53-AD A7 80 91 4D 9C FD 1F : ...5..ZS....M...
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10888] 00000010 : AB 5B FA CD 1B 42 BF EA-26 52 77 D8 18 19 9E E3 : .[...B..&Rw.....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10888] 00000020 : C8 92 D2 63 7D 74 00 00-0E 00 0A 00 13 00 62 00 : ...c}t........b.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10888] 00000030 : 09 00 63 00 12 00 FF 01-00                      : ..c......
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10888] Socket#6044116::EndReceive(OverlappedAsyncResult#62476613)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10888] Exiting Socket#6044116::EndReceive()    -> Int32#57
System.Net Information: 0 : [10888] SecureChannel#5773521 - Locating the private key for the certificate: [Version]
  V3

[Subject]
  CN=Test Labs (CA)
  Simple Name: Test Labs (CA)
  DNS Name: Test Labs (CA)

[Issuer]
  CN=Test Labs (CA)
  Simple Name: Test Labs (CA)
  DNS Name: Test Labs (CA)

[Serial Number]
  3120C1CCC8D477974B311D82A9B7881E

[Not Before]
  11/9/2016 1:10:37 PM

[Not After]
  12/31/2039 6:59:59 PM

[Thumbprint]
  EA7091EE4171B38C04DC210BFDEF0DBAE5289D8B

[Signature Algorithm]
  sha256RSA(1.2.840.113549.1.1.11)

[Public Key]
  Algorithm: RSA
  Length: 2048
  Key Blob: 30 82 01 0a 02 82 01 01 00 af 67 80 80 31 64 a2 6b a1 b1 36 ce 9e 16 ef 61 e3 26 25 e9 49 a9 cc 80 2c 3d d6 0e 60 01 65 78 cd ce a9 e9 cc a6 ac 3f 99 7d 02 df cd d3 ff 78 fe 1f cb 73 f5 26 70 db 30 70 f6 8d 8f 92 d2 77 1c ea 84 53 3c 43 e8 48 cc 52 d3 26 07 5f b3 33 b7 4e d6 fc 00 e4 32 82 76 11 f5 c9 df 98 3e af d8 da 5f 21 74 b2 64 38 f9 d1 b1 96 0c c3 81 12 f8 49 a6 54 42 0e 7d 89 13 f7 9f 45 1e 04 1f 7d 41 7c 44 f3 30 14 79 ee 7c 78 b0 d4 e2 e4 d6 cc 85 2d b1 94 95 fb 30 47 9a 86 90 6f 50 c8 ....
System.Net Information: 0 : [10888] SecureChannel#5773521 - Certificate is of type X509Certificate2 and contains the private key.
System.Net Information: 0 : [10888] AcquireCredentialsHandle(package = Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider, intent  = Inbound, scc     = System.Net.SecureCredential)
System.Net Information: 0 : [10888] AcceptSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = (null), inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, AcceptStream)
System.Net Information: 0 : [10888] AcceptSecurityContext(In-Buffer length=62, Out-Buffer length=0, returned code=AlgorithmMismatch).
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [4240] Socket#6044116::Dispose()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [4240] TcpClient#59817589::Close()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [4240] TcpClient#59817589::Dispose()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [4240] Exiting TcpClient#59817589::Dispose() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [4240] Exiting TcpClient#59817589::Close() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [4240] TcpListener#21950498::AcceptTcpClient()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [4240] Socket#37614147::Accept()
```

This succeeds:

```
System.Net.Sockets Information: 0 : [8344] Socket#6044116 - Accepted connection from 192.168.3.106:55907 to 192.168.3.106:7001.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [8344] Exiting Socket#37614147::Accept()    -> Socket#6044116
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [8344] TcpClient#59817589::TcpClient(Socket#6044116)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [8344] Exiting TcpClient#59817589::TcpClient() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [8344] Exiting TcpListener#21950498::AcceptTcpClient()  -> TcpClient#59817589
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [8344] TcpClient#59817589::GetStream()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [8344] Exiting TcpClient#59817589::GetStream()  -> NetworkStream#48209832
System.Net Information: 0 : [8344] SecureChannel#5773521::.ctor(hostname=?124, #clientCertificates=0, encryptionPolicy=RequireEncryption)
System.Net Information: 0 : [8344] Enumerating security packages:
System.Net Information: 0 : [8344]     Negotiate
System.Net Information: 0 : [8344]     NegoExtender
System.Net Information: 0 : [8344]     Kerberos
System.Net Information: 0 : [8344]     NTLM
System.Net Information: 0 : [8344]     TSSSP
System.Net Information: 0 : [8344]     pku2u
System.Net Information: 0 : [8344]     WDigest
System.Net Information: 0 : [8344]     Schannel
System.Net Information: 0 : [8344]     Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider
System.Net Information: 0 : [8344]     CREDSSP
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [8344] Socket#6044116::BeginReceive()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [8344] Exiting Socket#6044116::BeginReceive()   -> OverlappedAsyncResult#63094882
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14296] Data from Socket#6044116::PostCompletion
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14296] 00000000 : 16 03 00 00 A7                                  : .....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14296] Socket#6044116::EndReceive(OverlappedAsyncResult#63094882)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14296] Exiting Socket#6044116::EndReceive()    -> Int32#5
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14296] Socket#6044116::BeginReceive()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [14296] Exiting Socket#6044116::BeginReceive()  -> OverlappedAsyncResult#62476613
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13340] Data from Socket#6044116::PostCompletion
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13340] 00000000 : 01 00 00 A3 03 03 5A 53-AD 98 78 ED 38 1B 06 57 : ......ZS..x.8..W
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13340] 00000010 : 52 BF E5 61 58 A2 37 A3-AC 6E 18 83 AE 2E 25 EF : R..aX.7..n....%.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13340] 00000020 : 60 32 67 A3 BF D4 00 00-38 C0 30 C0 2F C0 28 C0 : `2g.....8.0./.(.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13340] 00000030 : 27 C0 14 C0 13 C0 2C C0-2B C0 24 C0 23 C0 0A C0 : '.....,.+.$.#...
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13340] 00000040 : 09 00 9D 00 9C 00 3D 00-3C 00 35 00 2F 00 0A 00 : ......=.<.5./...
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13340] 00000050 : 9F 00 9E 00 39 00 33 00-6A 00 40 00 38 00 32 00 : ....9.3.j.@.8.2.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13340] 00000060 : 13 01 00 00 42 00 00 00-09 00 07 00 00 04 3F 31 : ....B.........?1
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13340] 00000070 : 32 34 00 0A 00 06 00 04-00 17 00 18 00 0B 00 02 : 24..............
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13340] 00000080 : 01 00 00 0D 00 14 00 12-06 01 06 03 04 01 05 01 : ................
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13340] 00000090 : 02 01 04 03 05 03 02 03-02 02 00 23 00 00 00 17 : ...........#....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13340] 000000A0 : 00 00 FF 01 00 01 00                            : .......
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13340] Socket#6044116::EndReceive(OverlappedAsyncResult#62476613)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13340] Exiting Socket#6044116::EndReceive()    -> Int32#167
System.Net Information: 0 : [13340] SecureChannel#5773521 - Locating the private key for the certificate: [Version]
  V3

[Subject]
  CN=Test Labs (CA)
  Simple Name: Test Labs (CA)
  DNS Name: Test Labs (CA)

[Issuer]
  CN=Test Labs (CA)
  Simple Name: Test Labs (CA)
  DNS Name: Test Labs (CA)

[Serial Number]
  3120C1CCC8D477974B311D82A9B7881E

[Not Before]
  11/9/2016 1:10:37 PM

[Not After]
  12/31/2039 6:59:59 PM

[Thumbprint]
  EA7091EE4171B38C04DC210BFDEF0DBAE5289D8B

[Signature Algorithm]
  sha256RSA(1.2.840.113549.1.1.11)

[Public Key]
  Algorithm: RSA
  Length: 2048
  Key Blob: 30 82 01 0a 02 82 01 01 00 af 67 80 80 31 64 a2 6b a1 b1 36 ce 9e 16 ef 61 e3 26 25 e9 49 a9 cc 80 2c 3d d6 0e 60 01 65 78 cd ce a9 e9 cc a6 ac 3f 99 7d 02 df cd d3 ff 78 fe 1f cb 73 f5 26 70 db 30 70 f6 8d 8f 92 d2 77 1c ea 84 53 3c 43 e8 48 cc 52 d3 26 07 5f b3 33 b7 4e d6 fc 00 e4 32 82 76 11 f5 c9 df 98 3e af d8 da 5f 21 74 b2 64 38 f9 d1 b1 96 0c c3 81 12 f8 49 a6 54 42 0e 7d 89 13 f7 9f 45 1e 04 1f 7d 41 7c 44 f3 30 14 79 ee 7c 78 b0 d4 e2 e4 d6 cc 85 2d b1 94 95 fb 30 47 9a 86 90 6f 50 c8 ....
System.Net Information: 0 : [13340] SecureChannel#5773521 - Certificate is of type X509Certificate2 and contains the private key.
System.Net Information: 0 : [13340] AcquireCredentialsHandle(package = Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider, intent  = Inbound, scc     = System.Net.SecureCredential)
System.Net Information: 0 : [13340] AcceptSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = (null), inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, AcceptStream)
System.Net Information: 0 : [13340] AcceptSecurityContext(In-Buffer length=172, Out-Buffer length=1236, returned code=ContinueNeeded).
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13340] Socket#6044116::BeginSend()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [13340] Exiting Socket#6044116::BeginSend()     -> OverlappedAsyncResult#45653674
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [8396] Data from Socket#6044116::PostCompletion
```